# Why is a tuple of tuples of length 1 not actually a tuple unless I add a comma?

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, tuples, element

Given a tuple of tuples **T**:

```
(('a', 'b'))
```

and an individual tuple **t1**:

```
('a','b')
```

why does:

```
t1 in T
```

return False?

### UPDATE: From Ipython:

```
In [22]: T = (('a','b'))

In [23]: t1 = ('a','b')

In [24]: t1 in T
Out[24]: False
```

And how then to check that a tuple is in another tuple?

Comment: Are you sure it returns `False`, I guess it should return `True`

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? Where specifically are you getting this result? Is there an `if` that is evaluating in a wya you aren't expecting?

Comment: @IanAuld code added above

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is because T is not a tuple of tuples, it is just a tuple.  The comma makes a tuple, not the parentheses.  Should be:

```
>>> T = (('a','b'),)
>>> t1 = ('a', 'b')
>>> t1 in T
True
```

In fact, you can loose the outer parentheses:

```
>>> T = ('a','b'),
>>> t1 = 'a','b'
>>> type(T)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(T[0])
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(t1)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> t1 in T
True
```

Although sometimes they are needed for precedence, if in doubt put them in.  But remember, it is the comma that makes it a tuple.

Comment: I see this misunderstanding in a lot of places - it's not the parentheses that make the tuple, it's the comma. It can be an awkward one to spot though!

Comment: The comma makes a tuple? `type(t1)` shouldn't return tuple then. So if have a bunch of code that ends up creating a tuple of tuples whose length can no be known in advance, if I want to check for the presence of a single tuple, I first have to check lenght, and if it is 1, I have to add a comma?? Tell me this isn't so ...

Comment: @Pyderman `(1,2,3,)` is equivalent to `(1,2,3)`, so I would always add the comma

Comment: @Pyderman.  It isn't so.  It's not even clear what you mean.  The point is that the *literal" form of a one element tuple needs a comma.  If you are building a tuple programmatically then you won't be typing commas anyway.  Also `type(t1)` returns tuple because it is a tuple.  But not a tuple of tuples which is what you want.

Comment: Why shouldn't `type(t1)` return tuple, Pyderman? There's clearly a comma, right between `'a'` and `'b'`.

Comment: The comma makes the tuple. You actually don't even need the parenthesis at all. This will create a tuple: `t1 = 'a','b'`

Comment: @strubbly `T` is the tuple of tuples (or at least I thought it was .....). `t1` is the individual tuple

Comment: @Pyderman - ah yes see what you mean.  No - a trailing comma is only needed if the tuple is of length one. The point is that literal tuples need at least one comma.  Brackets with no comma have a different meaning, as in  `2 * (3 + 4)`

Answer (score 3):

Check again. You likely have a bug somewhere else in your code. This check does work.

As for the update, you're not creating a nested tuple.

```
(('a', 'b')) == ('a', 'b')
```

If you need a one-element tuple, you need a trailing coma:

```
(('a', 'b'),)
```

Comment: This should really be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @IanAuld: No, that is an answer.  What more can we say?

Comment: @IanAuld, ikaros45 Chillax people. Updated question, updated answer. You had a few minutes to actually answer the question but decided to dis this instead. Let's just help the OP instead.

Comment: @viraptor Thanks. So it seems that my single-item "tuple" of tuples is not really a tuple unless I add a comma after the single tuple. Seems daft.

Comment: @Pyderman It separates grouping from tuples. In cases like `(1 + 2) + 3`, you wouldn't want the to get a tuple from the first sum, right? Same applies to tuples -> `(('a', 'b') + ('c', 'd'))` is just grouping that sum rather than making a tuple out of the result.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this `(('a', 'b'))` does not make a tuple containing a tuple as you can see here:

```py
    >>> T = (('a','b'))
    >>> T
    ('a', 'b')
```

To make a single element tuple you need to add a trailing comma:

```py
    >>> T = (('a','b'),)
    >>> t1 in T
    True
    >>> T
    (('a', 'b'),)
```

In fact the parenthesis aren't even a requirement as this will also create a tuple:

```py
    >>> t1 = 'a','b'
    >>> t1
    ('a', 'b')
    >>> 1,2,3,4,5,6
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: As per my comment in  cdarke's answer: So if have a bunch of code that ends up creating a tuple of tuples whose length can no be known in advance, if I want to check for the presence of a single tuple, I first have to check length, and if it is 1, I have to add a comma??

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Pyderman In this case (length not known in advance), a list seems more appropriate to me in the first place...